# How to access deviceToken when registering for push notifications in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I should preface by saying I’ve already checked [this](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F24216632%2Fremote-notification-ios-8&ei=OMpgVIqGForC7AaMtoFQ&usg=AFQjCNFjLipfjxMQ3oiahrKN3R6C4OGXYg&sig2=EmXnpypmMK-1RBn2Y8xX9A&bvm=bv.79189006,d.ZGU) and [this](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F24426090%2Fget-device-token-in-ios-8&ei=OMpgVIqGForC7AaMtoFQ&usg=AFQjCNE3B0MfC5UCfBGP8QMdZN_c3txwMQ&sig2=aRbds1G0IlATQ2FX8u_SIg&bvm=bv.79189006,d.ZGU), but neither of these two accepted answers has solved my issue.

I’m using a third-party push notification service, and their `registerDevice` method requires a `deviceToken`, such as that returned by `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`. However, in iOS 8, that method is deprecated, and replaced by `application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:`, which as you can see has no `deviceToken`.

I’ve tried adding this method, which is called, and I hoped would trigger a manual call to `didRegisterForRemoteNotifications`, but it hasn’t worked. I used this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Basically, I need to access that `deviceToken`, and I have no means of doing so with the newly-preferred `application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` callback.

Everything is fine in iOS 7, but in iOS 8, that token seems unavailable. How can I solve this?

Comment: What is it that you need the device token for?

Comment: The third party service that I use require it, for segmentation, tagging per user, etc. And yes, I have already asked them for advice, but I’d rather not wait for them to email back and SO are usually much faster ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you are mistaking. the callback for `registerForRemoteNotifications` is `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`, which is not deprecated in ios8 at all. i just tested this works fine.

in your app delegate, for ios8 you do

```
UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                                 categories:nil];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

the callback you get is

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the callback. I've just noticed I get an error in `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotifications`, so I'm looking at that right now. That's probably the root cause.

Comment: please inform us how it ends

Comment: Looks like it’s an issue with provisioning. Urrrrgh!

Comment: Still wrangling with it!